# BPMN gateway for: Task A must happen. Either Task B or Task C must happen. The 2 tasks are happening at same time/in parallel

Tags: gateway, bpmn

Should I use one diverging gateway and one converging gateway or one diverging parallel gateway and one converging complex gateway? Which option would be better for my project?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For two or more concurrent tasks, use parallel gateways for forking and joining the sequence flow. In contrast, a diverging (exclusive) gateway will select only one of the outgoing sequence flows.

Examples can be found here:
https://www.visual-paradigm.com/guide/bpmn/bpmn-gateway-types

So what you probably want is an exclusive gateway for Tasks B and C, and Task A concurrently to those with a parallel gateway:

[image]